# Manage HTTP schema to deep link into my app?

Tags: ios, deep-linking

I'm digging around with Deep Linking for an iOS app and I'm successfully managing deeplinks with a custom schema based on my app.

This means that whenever the user taps a link (in Safari for instance) that has the schema `com.MYAPP://aPage?someInfo=value`, the app is opened and the user is redirected as expected.

The problem is that I don't know how to handle links with HTTP schema, as a browser would do. I want the same behavior to apply for `http://www.MYAPP.com/aPage?someInfo=value`, but from what I've researching this is not possible unless a third party solution is involved. Is this correct?

Another alternative seems to have a redirection in my server, but it seems a bit of a long shot to solve an issue that should be much simpler.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    [self handleURL:url];
    return YES;
}

- (void) handleURL:(NSURL*)url{
    if (!url)
        return ;

    if ([url.host isEqualToString:@"p"]) {
        NSArray* array = [url pathComponents];

        if ([array count] == 2 )
            [self goToScreen:[array objectAtIndex:1]];
    }
}

-(void) goToScreen:(NSString*)name{
    if ([name isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        [self.tbc setSelectedIndex:0];
    }
    else if ([name isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        [self.tbc setSelectedIndex:1];
    }
    else if ([name isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
        [self.tbc setSelectedIndex:2];
    }
    else if ([name isEqualToString:@"3"]) {
        [self.tbc setSelectedIndex:0];
        detailsViewController* details = [[[detailsViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        UINavigationController* nav = [[self.tbc viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        [nav popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        [nav pushViewController:details animated:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't apply to handling an http schema. If i get a link `http://www.myapp.com/route?param` it will never open the app, nor call openURL in my AppDelegate.